# Require at least one prop to be passed to component [typescript]

Tags: reactjs, typescript

quick question - let's say I have a component like this:

```
interface ComponentInterface {
    nameA: string;
    nameB?: string;
}

const Component: React.FC<ComponentInterface> = (props) => {
     const { nameA, nameB } = props 
     const name = nameB || nameA;

     return <div>Hello World! Name: {name}</div>
}
```

is there a way in Typescript to make nameB mandatory if we don't pass nameA?

It feels bad to write `<Component nameA={""} nameB={"John"} />` and I dont want to turn nameA into `nameA?: string` because I want at least one of the props to be passed.

This is an oversimplified version ofc. Ty in advance! <3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, You can use union type:

```js
interface Props1 {
    nameA: string;
    nameB?: string;
}

interface Props2 {
    nameB: string;
}

type Props = Props1 | Props2
```

It is mean, if you pass `nameA`, `nameB` is optional. But if you don't pass `nameA` - `nameB` is required.